# sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Row with identity key can't be loaded into an object; the polymorphic discriminator column refers to mapped class

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, polymorphic-relationship

I have some legacy code that has a polymorphic base class definition and two sub classes.

The entity definitions are below.

```
class Field(Base):
    __tablename__ = "field"
    field_parent = Column(String(64), index=True)

    controller_id = Column(ForeignKey('controller.id'))
    controller = relationship("Controller")
    node_id = Column(ForeignKey("node.id"))
    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_on": field_parent}

class ControllerField(Field):
    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": "controller"}

class NodeField(Field):
    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": "node"}

class Controller:
    __tablename__ = "controller"

class Node:
    __tablename__ = "node"
```

Some example data from my local DB.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ic7i.png)

I'm trying to query the 'controller' table and SQLAlchemy is trying to load all the class's relationships (my assumption). When it gets to the polymorphic subclass the query fails because the 'field' table contains foreign key references to both the 'controller' and 'node' tables and because the latter is supposed to be of type 'node' it still has an FK to the 'controller' table and thus the identity is not the right type. It seems like SQLAlchemy doesn't like this in the current configuration. The stacktrace can be seen below.

```
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/h11_impl.py", line 396, in run_asgi
    result = await app(self.scope, self.receive, self.send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 45, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 199, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 112, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 181, in __call__
    raise exc from None
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 159, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/cors.py", line 78, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 82, in __call__
    raise exc from None
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 71, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 580, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 390, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 199, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 112, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 181, in __call__
    raise exc from None
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 159, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/cors.py", line 78, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 82, in __call__
    raise exc from None
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 71, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 580, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 241, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 52, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 201, in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 150, in run_endpoint_function
    return await run_in_threadpool(dependant.call, **values)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/concurrency.py", line 40, in run_in_threadpool
    return await loop.run_in_executor(None, func, *args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 58, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/usr/src/app/./app/subapp/shim/v2/endpoints/controller.py", line 25, in get
    return Wrapper(data=service.get(id=id, controller_category=controllerCategory, condensed=condensed))
  File "/usr/src/app/./app/subapp/shim/services/controller_service.py", line 23, in get
    "controller": self.__append_nodes(controller.dict(logged_in_user=self.__logged_in_user))
  File "/usr/src/app/./app/database/base_new.py", line 28, in dict
    rs = getattr(self, relationship.key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 481, in __get__
    return self.impl.get(state, dict_)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 926, in get
    value = self._fire_loader_callables(state, key, passive)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 962, in _fire_loader_callables
    return self.callable_(state, passive)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/strategies.py", line 892, in _load_for_state
    return self._emit_lazyload(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/strategies.py", line 1056, in _emit_lazyload
    result = result.unique().scalars().all()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/result.py", line 1319, in all
    return self._allrows()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/result.py", line 400, in _allrows
    rows = self._fetchall_impl()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/result.py", line 1232, in _fetchall_impl
    return self._real_result._fetchall_impl()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/result.py", line 1626, in _fetchall_impl
    return list(self.iterator)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 124, in chunks
    rows = [proc(row) for row in fetch]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 124, in <listcomp>
    rows = [proc(row) for row in fetch]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 1274, in polymorphic_instance
    raise sa_exc.InvalidRequestError(
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Row with identity key (<class 'app.database.models.field.Field'>, (150,), None) can't be loaded into an object; the polymorphic discriminator column 'field.field_parent' refers to mapped class NodeField->field, which is not a sub-mapper of the requested mapped class ControllerField->field
```

If I delete the reference to the 'controller' table on the instance with identity 'node' the queries run as expected. As this is legacy code I can't just delete the extra FK references as we don't know what will break if we do this. Is there a way that I can tell SQLAlchemy to load the correct definition without looking at the FK reference or something?

Extra info:

FastAPI Docker Container with a MySQL database
Python 3.8
SQLAlchemy 1.4.21

Answer (score 0):

I've come across the same stuff here, hence I'm going through your post ;) The obvious solution is to select a common ancestor class defining the concrete polymorphic identity via filter or smth.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue as well and found a very simple solution: the base class needs also to have a polymorphic identity (e.g. 'base'). Set this value to be the default value of 'field_parent'.

The new code looks like this:

```
class Field(Base):
    __tablename__ = "field"

    field_parent = Column(String(64), index=True, default="base")
    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_on": field_parent,
                       "polymorphic_identity": "base"}

    controller_id = Column(ForeignKey("controller.id"))
    controller = relationship("Controller")
    node_id = Column(ForeignKey("node.id"))
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you try to put `__tablename__ = None` line in all those sub-classes which do not include `__tablename__`?

```
class Field(Base):
    __tablename__ = "field"
    ...
    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_on": field_parent}

class ControllerField(Field):
    __tablename__ = None
    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": "controller"}

class NodeField(Field):
    __tablename__ = None
    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": "node"}
```

Another approach is to use `declared_attr` decorator, no `__tablename__ = None` required anymore:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import (
    declarative_mixin,
    declared_attr,
    has_inherited_table,
)

@declarative_mixin
class Field(Base):
    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(cls):
        if has_inherited_table(cls):
            return None
        return cls.__name__.lower()
    ...
    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_on": field_parent}

class ControllerField(Field):
    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": "controller"}

class NodeField(Field):
    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": "node"}
```